# Why does DeepSkyStacker output a "glitch" image with just vertical lines

Tags: astrophotography, image-stacking

Yesterday I've got my new tracker (iOptron SkyTracker), and took about 30 shots of the Orion Nebula (with my Canon EOS 6D and 70-200mm f/2.8 lens at 200mm, f/4, 6s exposure of each frame) and got home.

Here is a (cropped) sample from one of the raw files, and they are all the same, almost perfectly aligned etc:

[image]

All the other raws are perfectly normal like the image above. I've fired up DeepSkyStacker, filled the raws, (as this was just a tracker test, I don't have dark or flat frames) and gave it a spin with the recommended settings. After about 10 minutes, this is the result:

[image]

The result is just a glitch image consisting of vertical bars. Here is my recommended settings:

[image]

I also don't think there is any problem with reading the raws or aligning them correctly:

[image]

I haven't touched my stacking settings, it's as they are by default. What have I done wrong?

Comment: It appears that you may have an image of the image histogram information. (A wild guess) Is there a chance that you are imaging the wrong data file that might be corrected in preferences?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems with DSS with the RAW files from my camera. Even though the images are previewed correctly in DSS, stacking didn't work.

The solution in my case was to convert the RAW files to DNG with the Adobe DNG converter, also using the newest version of Deep Sky Stacker wich is (afaik) 4.1.1

Answer (score -2):

Before using Deep Sky Stacker, Use a RAW image preview application like "Adobe Bridge"(or Other App) to review and organize your images.  Any photos with football-shaped stars from hiccups in auto guiding are tossed in the recycling bin.  The same goes for frames with airplanes, satellites or passing clouds.